# Insert with Array in Values with On Conflict

Tags: postgresql

I can't seem to get this postgresql execute to work.

```
INSERT INTO table (x, y) 
VALUES ('somestring', '{0.123, -0.123}') 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;
```

I get the error:

`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "ON"`

I've tried a variety of things, and I'm not very well versed in postgresql or sql in general. I'm on version 9.5.1 of Postgresql.

I'm also using SQLAlchemy (Python Lib). Is there a way to check what version of Postgresql my SQLAlchemy is using?

Comment: `"somestring"` should be in single quotes.

Comment: To clarify what @pumbo is saying: standard SQL uses double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names) that are case sensitive, contain spaces, ...; single quotes are for string literals.

Comment: Ah thank you for the tip! Though, that still doesn't fix the problem :/

Comment: Run `select version()` to find the Postgres version you are using. Also: does the table have a primary key? If yes which one?

Comment: `id` is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what may cause the conflict.

Example from the docs:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (7, 'Redline GmbH')
    ON CONFLICT (did) DO NOTHING;
```

edit: I am referring to the (did) part

Comment: For the `do nothing` option the `(did)` is not required